# Android Archive Library dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, aar

I'm creating a library project so that the code and ui could be reuse in multiple project. The library project contains some dependencies/module. Is it possible to only import the .aar without importing the the require dependencies? I've read the transitive dependencies but I want it to be a local .aar file.

Answer (score 0):

Name your library as 'com.xxx:lsdk'.

You should do these things:

1.Set up your own maven server,such as :"http://maven.xxx.com/";

2.Upload your lsdk.aar to your maven server with target version code such as '1.0.1'.

3.Modify your gradle scripts below:

```
repositories {
    maven {     
    url "http://maven.xxx.com/"
    }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

compile “com.xxx:lsdk-1.0.1"
```